# java regex match string with asterisks

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have to create a regular expression that compares strings like those inserted into the following list:

```
ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add("text1/*");
entries.add("text2/*/*");
entries.add("text2/*/*/*");
entries.add("text1/*/*");
entries.add("text1/value1/*");
entries.add("*/*");
```

If I've a string like "text1/value1/value2" how can I understand which is the matching one iterating through entries? Among the entries above, for example, the correct one would be the fifth entry "text1/value1/*".

Comment: so what is the correct pattern you are looking for? is it anything/anthing/* ?

Comment: yes it's "text1/value1/*" the fifth one

Comment: i edited my answer with a better regex. test it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT1: figured out better regex. You can apply similar logic to your needs. I'm guessing you have to build the regex based on an input string?

Explanation of the pattern used:

```
    ^([^/*]+)/([^/*]+)/[*]$

    ^ start of string
    [^/*] match any character except / or *
    + is a quantifier that matches preceding char or group 0 to many times
    / followed by the character /
    [^/*] match any character except / or *
    / followed by the character /
    [*] followed by only 1 more character which is * and not something else
    $ end of string
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
    entries.add("text1/*");
    entries.add("text2/*/*");
    entries.add("text2/*/*/*");
    entries.add("text1/*/*");
    entries.add("text1/value1/*");
    entries.add("*/*");

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([^/*]+)/([^/*]+)/[*]$", 2);

    for (String entry : entries) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found correct entry: " + entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about writing a regular expression for this, it would seem a whole lot easier to just parse it character by character instead.

However I just did a project that used path matchers provided by the Spring framework and it looks  like a perfect job for the [`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html).

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher();

    String path = "text1/value1/value2";
    ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
    entries.add("text1/*");
    entries.add("text2/*/*");
    entries.add("text2/*/*/*");
    entries.add("text1/*/*");
    entries.add("text1/value1/*");
    entries.add("*/*");

    String bestMatch = null;
    // use a pattern comparator to see what pattern best matches this path
    Comparator<String> comp = pathMatcher.getPatternComparator(path);
    // go through all our patterns
    for(String pattern : entries) {
        // make sure the pattern matches the path
        if(pathMatcher.match(pattern, path)) {
            // check if we already have a match
            if(bestMatch != null) {
                // if we have a match take the best one of those 2... the one that best matches that is
                if(comp.compare(bestMatch, pattern) > 0) {
                    bestMatch = pattern;
                }
            } else {
                // no match found yet, lets use this one
                bestMatch = pattern;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bestMatch);
}
```